# Am I correct with the following converging/diverging series

Tags: analysis

Have two series, just a quick check of some simple series:

$\sum _{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\sqrt {2n^{2}-3}}$

Considering 
$\frac {1}{\sqrt {2n^{2}-3}}$ >  $\frac {1}{\sqrt {4n^{2}}}$ = $\frac {1}{2n}$

Since 
$\sum _{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{2n}$ $\rightarrow$ Diverges, hence by the camparsion test we have that $\sum _{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\sqrt {2n^{2}-3}}$
 diverges.

The second one is 
$\sum _{1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$

Consdering $(-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} \le |(-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}|= (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$

We know that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ converges, hence we have that $\sum _{1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ coverges so again by the comparison test we have that $\sum _{1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$
 converges absolutely $\Rightarrow$ converges,

many thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}$ converges, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges...

Comment: First one is OK, but start at $n=2$, or your calculator will blow up. The second is very not OK, your terms are alternately close to $e$ or close to $-e$, so partial sums bounce around a lot, and don't settle down.

Comment: So would i just show that the sequence converges too two different limits, say for example $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first series you mention diverges, and the reason you give is correct. However, it is not correct to say "$\to$ Diverges", as this would be as saying "approaches diverges" (or "converges to diverges"), which makes no sense. You could say that it "diverges to infinity" or write $\to +\infty$. Anyway, this is minor. Your argument is fine.

On the other hand, the second series diverges, and your argument is incorrect. This is because the *sequence* $(1+\frac1n)^n$ converges, but that is not what is being asked. You are asked to add up together the terms of the sequence, which is a completely different thing.

The usual way of dealing with the second example is to use the $n$-th term test, which says that *if a series converges, its $n$th term converges to 0*. Here, the terms are $(-1)^n\left(1+\cfrac1n\right)^n$ which do not converge to 0 because they do not converge at all. In fact, in absolute value, they approach $e$. It follows that the series *diverges*.

---

Note that you do not need to know or recognize that the terms of the second series in absolute value approach $e$ to conclude that the series diverges. Just note that 
 $$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\ge 1, $$
so also $|(-1)^n(1+\frac1n)^n|\ge1$, and the terms cannot converge to 0.

Comment: Oh is this the non-null test, if so totally forgot about that.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I had seen it called that way in a while.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument is ok (you should start the series at $n=2$ though).

The second is not.  As you imply, for the second series, you should be able to compute the *value of* the limit of (part of) the  *sequence of terms you are adding*: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+{1\over n})^n$.  Then, based on the value of this limit, can the series converge?

Hint: The limit above is not zero. Thus $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}[(-1)^n(1+{1\over n})^n]\ne0$. What can you say about a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\ne0$?

Comment: Many thanks for that, it diverges due to the non-null test?

Comment: @user24930 If "non-null test" means what I think it means, then yes.